# How to get Keyword key and keyword name in DXA

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-1.2, keyword

I have created model in DXA

```
namespace Sdl.Web.Web.Common.Models
{
    public class Test:EntityModel
    {
        public Tag Test{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm able to get the Keyword key @Model.Test.Key but to get keyword name I tried for accessing Keyword Name but didn't find it.

Please let me know how to get the Keyword Name in DXA

Comment: Note that namespace `Sdl.Web.Common.Models` is intended for View Models provided as part of the DXA Framework. It is not recommended to define your own View Models in that namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Class `Tag` has a `DisplayText` property which reflects the Keyword's Description or Title (if Description is not set).

In DXA 1.7 a new (base) class `KeywordModel` has been introduced, which provides direct access to all Keyword properties.

Seeing that you are still on a relatively ancient version of DXA, I would recommend upgrading to the latest. Unfortunately, DXA 1.7 does not support 2013 SP1.

Comment: thanks , using DisplayText able to get the keyword desciption